# Build an NSArray of day NSStrings with missing date determined from NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to build an NSArray of NSStrings.  Each NSString is a day of the week e.g. Mon, Tues etc.

There needs to be 6 items in the array i.e. 6 days of the week.

The missing day must be determined from an NSDate object.

The first item in the array needs to be the day after the missing day and then ordered by days of the week.

e.g. MissingDate = Wed
     Array = Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue

Can anyone give me help with this, I seem to become a total nube with code relating to time!

Comment: This smells like you're asking someone to do your homework....

Comment: I have written loads of code to try and solve this problem but it seems so messy, I thought I would get some help yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use number 1~7 to do the logic work

then use NSDateFormatter to translate number to Weekday string

I'm not sure if this is the answer you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSDateFormatter dateFromString to parse each day. You then can use NSDateComponents to get the day of week as a number. Find the missing number and then do the reverse - get an NSDate from the NSDateComponents with the missing number, then use NSDateFormatter to parse this 'stringFromDate' to get the day.